# MvvmCross Navigating to TabViewController inside custom IosPresenter

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm having trouble Navigating to a MvxTabBarViewController from my main view, and I think there's something I'm missing with my IosViewPresenter, which utilizes a single root view with a NavigationBar and pages in a ContentView.

```
public class ContainerPresenter : MvxIosViewPresenter
{
    public static MvxNavigationController NavigationController = null;
    public static UIView MenuView = null;

    private UIView _containerView;
    private MvxViewController _rootController;

    public ContainerPresenter(IMvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (NavigationController == null)
        {
            // First controller called from main hamburger menu.  Must have decorator: WrapInNavigationController = true
            base.Show(request);
        }

        else
        {
            // Subsequent controllers called from main menu or other views 
            MvxViewController c = _rootController.CreateViewControllerFor(request) as MvxViewController;
            string val = "";
            if (request.PresentationValues != null)
            {
                request.PresentationValues.TryGetValue("NavigationMode", out val);
            }
            if (val.Equals("Push", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                // Push new controller onto navigation stack
                PushViewControllerIntoStack(NavigationController, c, true);
            }
            else
            {

                // Replace stack in existing navigation controller with new controller
                UIViewController[] controllers = { c };

                // SetViewControllers unloads all the navigation bar buttons
                // Don't animate to avoid visible refresh when switching root menu items
                NavigationController.SetViewControllers(controllers, false);
                NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(AlertItem.GetAlertItems(), false);
                NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(HamburgerItem.Button, false);

            }
        }
    }

    protected override MvxNavigationController CreateNavigationController(UIViewController viewController)
    {
        // One NavigationController instance for all views
        NavigationController = base.CreateNavigationController(viewController);
        NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;
        //NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(15, 79, 140);
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(33, 33, 33);
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;

        NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(HamburgerItem.Button, false);

        return NavigationController;
    }



    protected override void SetWindowRootViewController(UIViewController controller, MvxRootPresentationAttribute attribute = null)
    {
        if (_window.RootViewController == null)
        {
            // Insert MainView as root controller, subsequent root menu_item controllers will use MainView.ContainerView as root
            base.SetWindowRootViewController(controller, attribute);
            _rootController = controller as MvxViewController;

            // Hack to get around: 'MainView.ContainerView' is inacessible due to its protection level
            // _containerView = (_window.RootViewController as MainView).ContainerView;
            _containerView = _window.RootViewController.View.ViewWithTag(1);
            MenuView = _window.RootViewController.View.ViewWithTag(2);
        }
        else
        {
            // Move root menu_item controller to ContainerView
            controller.View.Frame = _containerView.Bounds;
            controller.WillMoveToParentViewController(_window.RootViewController);
            _containerView.AddSubview(controller.View);
            _window.RootViewController.AddChildViewController(controller);
            controller.DidMoveToParentViewController(_window.RootViewController);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm following the tab example provided in the playground at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground, my base tab view I'm calling looks like this

```
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public partial class ItemDetailBaseView : MvxTabBarViewController<ItemDetailBaseViewModel>
{


    private bool _isPresentedFirstTime = true;

    public ItemDetailBaseView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded"); //<----Never called
    }


    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad(); //<----Never called

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated); //<----Never called

        if (ViewModel != null && _isPresentedFirstTime)
        {
            _isPresentedFirstTime = false;
            ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModelsCommand.ExecuteAsync(null);
        }
    }
```

While my tab views look like this

```
public class ItemDetailTabViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public ItemDetailTabViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override void ViewAppeared()
    {
        base.ViewAppeared();
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy so far, I navigate to it with

```
_navigationService.Navigate<ItemDetailBaseViewModel>(new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "TabbedPage", "Push" } }));
```

I get "Navigate requested" but nothing else happens, no view change, not as much as a flicker.  As I commented above, nothing in ItemDetailBaseView is called.  According to the sample, ViewWillAppear should be called after navigation request, and then the command should populate, but I'm not getting anything.  I've even tried catching the request in the Presenter, and making the controller the root view, to no success and I'm out of ideas.

Thank you

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, I ended up running into a lot of issues with tabs.  If I remember correctly, I ended up implementing something like a pageview to scroll between "tabs" I created at the bottom.  I haven't dug into these project files in a few months though, sorry.